# When is .zprofile file read?

Tags: shell, zsh

I am using `.zprofile` to set up some stuff, and I assume it is evaluated everytime I log in to given user. Am I correct?

Comment: Not if the user uses bash, ksh, tcsh or any other shell except zsh.

Answer (score 1):

It is not evaluated everytime of you are using `tcsh` or `ksh`. So probably it is evaluated only for `zsh`.

From [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch03_03.htm):

> **zsh**
>
> As always, zsh is very flexible. Startup files are read from the
>   directory named in the ZDOTDIR environment variable, if any;[6]
>   otherwise, from HOME. All shells read the global /etc/zshenv and your
>   .zshenv files. If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from
>   /etc/zprofile and then your .zprofile. Then, if the shell is
>   interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc and your .zshrc.
>   Finally, if the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and your .zlogin
>   files are read.